# What are anomalous threshold singularities

Tags: scattering, s-matrix-theory

In the papers of the 1950s and 1960s, I see reference to [anomalous threshold singularities](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22anomalous+threshold+singularities%22). What are these? Is there a good reference that discusses this subject?

Answer (score 3):

"Anomalous" means that they're coming from quantum corrections, loops. "Threshold" means that they appear because some loop momenta approach a threshold for production at this very point – virtual particles are just becoming real. "Singularities" mean that these conditions obeyed by a loop Feynman diagram lead to a singular behavior in the resulting amplitude.

See e.g.

> http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02755022?LI=true
>   http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0111261

The last preprint mentions the anomalous threshold singularities in the context of their major application, the 1978 Coleman-Thun mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Anomalous thresholds are branch points in the complex plane of scattering amplitudes/Greens functions that are not easily deducible from unitarity.  The book "The Analytic S-Matrix" by R.J. Eden explains it well, and shows how it may be deduced non-trivilaly from unitarity considerations.